# 404 error for CodeBlocks repository when I update my system

Tags: package-management, ppa, code-blocks

I installed Code:Blocks on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. It works fine for now and I don't have any problem with it. But when I update my system using

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

I get an error saying

```
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Now, when I delete `http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu bionic` in the Software Center, Code:Blocks doesn't run the programs I've written. Having this error doesn't seem to harm anything but it is annoying.

How to solve this? I'm taking C courses in school, so I need some compiler in order to do my homeworks, but I am open to use something different. Thanks

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy codeblocks` to the question. What version of CodeBlock do you want to install?

Comment: `Codeblocks` package available on Universe repository see [this](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/base/codeblocks) or at the  `pasgui`'s ppa like  mentioned @Norbert answered!!!

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned - the [`ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks-stable`](https://launchpad.net/~damien-moore/+archive/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable) do not have packages for 18.04.

But [search on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=codeblocks) for Code::Blocks related PPAs results in other PPA named [`ppa:pasgui/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~pasgui/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic).

You can add it with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pasgui/ppa
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

and you will get CodeBlocks 17.12.

Optionally you can install contrib plugins with

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib
```

and enjoy the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

That PPA appears to be for older versions of Ubuntu that don't include a modern version of the `codeblocks` package:

- https://launchpad.net/~damien-moore/+archive/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable

Notice it's for 16.04 versions of Ubuntu, which is why your modern (18.04 bionic) version cannot find files on that PPA. It doesn't make a difference though because Ubuntu Bionic contains `Version: 16.01+dfsg-2.1` of `codeblocks` anyhow.

If you want to compile C code on Ubuntu the easiest way to make sure you have the compiler and it's associated files is to install the `build-essential` package:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

You should now have the `gcc` and `g++` commands for building C/C++ and other languages supported by it. Save this as `hello.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("hello\n"); }
```

Then compile it:

```
gcc hello.c
```

Then run it:

```
./a.out
```